# What could cause a dialog to hang in a .NET application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I'm investigating why dialog windows in a VB.NET WinForms application hangs/freezes sporadically (about 6 times a day). The controls in the window remain visually active (hover state, pressed state etc. work), but you can't type in the input fields, and clicking buttons doesn't do anything. Even the close window [x] button doesn't work. And you can't change focus to the parent window.

A workaround that was discovered by chance is to change the screen resolution back and forth. That "unfreezes" the window so you can continue working.

The bug started appearing after migration to Windows 7. The system has been running for years on Windows XP without problems. I haven't been able to reproduce it yet, so debugging isn't an option right now. I am merely trying to isolate the possible sources to the problem.

What could be blocking a .NET application like this?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx

Comment: Are you hearing a 'ding' when clicking on the form when it is frozen? Is it possible a modal dialog is open somewhere? I run across this on occasion with many programs - I call it "pop under." It isn't obvious at all that the dialog is open until you trash around an bit and it finally appears. You can't tell if it was there al along or just appeared so sometimes it appears your action "fixed" the problem. I'm not sure how to prevent this issue - perhaps provide populate the property that indicates ownership of the dialog.

Comment: We currntly assume it isn't a "pop under", @rheitzman - but good point

Comment: The only time I have seen such freezes, it was about too much work on UIThread. Maybe some of your processing should have been done in another Thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vb.net program that would periodically hang as well.

A few users have reported that Logitech's Setpoint (mouse) software caused my program to freeze shortly after start-up.  In these cases exiting the Setpoint software resolves the problem.

Are you using Setpoint?

Also, as I understand it, newer versions of Setpoint don't cause this conflict.